# Error while running customized java class

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have created a sequence file out of directory and then given index according to groups I want so that I can create groups using that index. This groups are then given one by one to my customized java class which gives information based on the file present in the group.

My problem is that some time it runs perfectly but some time gives different errors like null pointer exception, data type of field not found.

The problem is may be due to size of group. Because I am creating folder based group and then do the fetches the information from that folder inside my customized jar.

So how can I resolve this issue?
Below is my java class code:

```
public class OperateDirectory extends EvalFunc<DataBag>{
    public TupleFactory tupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    public BagFactory bagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();

    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<String> protoTuple = new ArrayList<>();
        DataBag dataBag = bagFactory.newDefaultBag();

        /* Create Directory */
        if(input == null)
            return dataBag;
        if(input.size() != 2)
            return dataBag;

        long id = (long)input.get(0);
        DataBag infoBag = (DataBag)input.get(1);
        Iterator<Tuple> it = infoBag.iterator();
        File dir = new File("/tmp/TestFolder"+id);
        if(dir.exists())
        {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(dir);
        }
        else
        {
            dir.mkdir();
        }

        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Tuple file_details = (Tuple)it.next();
            if(file_details != null && file_details.size()==3)
            {
                String file_name = (String)file_details.get(1);
                BytesWritable file_contents = (BytesWritable)file_details.get(2);
                File f = new File(dir.getPath()+"/"+file_name);
                f.deleteOnExit();
                writeToFile(file_contents, f);
            }
        }

        /* Perform operation here */

        File f = new File("output"+id+".log");
        ProcessBuilder performProcess1 = new ProcessBuilder("processes/processor", dir.getPath(),f.getPath());
        Process process1 = performProcess1.start();

        try
        {
            process1.waitFor();
            if(f.exists() && f.length()>0)
            {
               ProcessBuilder performProcess2 = new ProcessBuilder("perl", "scripts/ParseFile.pl", f.getPath());
               Process process2 = performProcess2.start();

               InputStream is = process2.getInputStream();
               InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
               String line;

               while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
               {
                   if(!line.isEmpty())
                   {
                       String [] tmpArray = line.split(",");
                       if(tmpArray.length == 2)
                       {
                           protoTuple.clear();
                           protoTuple.add(tmpArray[0]);
                           protoTuple.add(tmpArray[1]);
                           dataBag.add(tupleFactory.newTuple(protoTuple));
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
            else
            {
                protoTuple.clear();
                protoTuple.add("Error");
                protoTuple.add("File "+f.getPath()+" does not exists ");
                dataBag.add(tupleFactory.newTuple(protoTuple));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            protoTuple.clear();
            protoTuple.add("Error ");
            protoTuple.add(e.getMessage());
            dataBag.add(tupleFactory.newTuple(protoTuple));
        }

        try
        {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(dir);
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
        return dataBag;
    }
    void writeToFile(BytesWritable value, File binaryFile) throws IOException{
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(binaryFile);
    fileOut.write(value.getBytes(), 0, value.getLength());
    fileOut.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please give more details such as input/output expectations and stacktraces. Thanks!

Comment: I will explain steps what i am doing:First creates sequence file out of directory. Then assigning indexes to each record (i.e. reocord=> index, file_md5, file_contents). Here indexes are given by my own customized java class. Then records are grouped according to indexes and given to the next process which is mentioned above. My problem is that when group size is less it works correctly but when i have groups of more than 200 size it fails with different errors for e.g. Data type not found, null pointer exception. Since exceptions are different i am not getting trace of how to solve this.